# Rails 3 mailer interceptor conflicting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, conflict, interceptor, mailer

I followed tutorial on RailsCasts (Sending email revised version). I had to change the development file in "config" because it was not working properly.Always when I try to add an interceptor (tell Rails to send the email to me as well) it will stop sending it to the user. If I disable it, it will send it to the user but not to me. I do not get any errors at all. Thank you !

```
Here are my files:
My config/development.rb file:

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:user_name            => "admin@gmail.com",
:password             => 'admin',
:authentication       => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
 } 

User controller:
UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver


User mailer file:
app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
default from: "admin@gmail.com"

def signup_confirmation(user)
@user = user
mail to: user.email, subject: "Sign Up Confirmation"    
end
end

lib/development_mail_interceptor.rb file

 class DevelopmentMailInterceptor  
  def self.delivering_email(message)  
    message.subject = "[#{message.to}] #{message.subject}"  
    message.to = "admin@gmail.com"  
  end  
end

config/initiliazers/setup_mail.rb

require 'development_mail_interceptor'
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(DevelopmentMailInterceptor) if 
Rails.env.development?
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the email's to, not adding to it.

```
message.to = "admin@gmail.com"
```

try one of these:

```
message.to << "admin@gmail.com" 
message.to += "admin@gmail.com"
```